# Right aligned ActionBarDrawerToggle for RTL languages

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library, navigation-drawer

Is it possible to customize [`ActionBarDrawerToggle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html) to put its icon on the right side of action bar?

The `layout_gravity="right"` applied to `DrawerLayout` `ListView` is only affecting the list of menus not the `ActionBarDrawerToggle`.

Comment: Have you solved it ?